# Input type=number doesn't show value

Tags: html

I just try to show a saved value in this DOM node:

```
<input type="number" step="any" name="@f.Id" placeholder="Description" class="form-control" value="9,13" style="width: 100%" />
```

But it doesn't show a value property. And I can't get why? It's so simple HTML that I event don't know where I could miss.
P.S. I use the Google Chrome browser.
P.P.S. It's more interesting that this element works perfect:

```
<input type="number" step="1" name="@f.Id" placeholder="@f.Description" class="form-control" value="9" style="width: 100%" />
```

Comment: The comma is causing the problem, since it's looking for either a number with a decimal point or an integer.  See @Gilsdav's answer below.

Comment: You could have read the **MDN page** before asking..saving yourself the time and to everyone else

Comment: @vsync yes, but that's a tiny bit that is very easily missed, especially if your native language doesn't use a dot as separator.

Comment: @vsync, my browser returns me a value with comma. So, I was sure that I need to use `,`. Although you're right, of course, I have should looked specifications.

Answer (score 8):

Please use dot on your number:

```
<input type="number" step="any" name="@f.Id" placeholder="Description" class="form-control" value="9.13" style="width: 100%" />
```

Javascript and html use dot for decimal.

Comment: That said, if you add the proper `lang="xx"` attribute to your `<html>` tag, the browser converts the value automatically from the dot notation to the right format and back.

Comment: Thank you! It works but wtf? Browser returns a `9,13` but accepts `9.13`. =)

Comment: The browser should post back a `9.13` to the server. It may display a `9,13`, though, if the locale says so. If it posts a `9,13` back, then there's some other JS intercepting things before form submit.

Comment: Thank you very much! Another developer added a value convertation before submitting I didn't noticed. Just the page is enough large.